# Validate that CAST date value is greater than another CAST date value not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

[image]

I am trying to check if a `VARCHAR` value that I'm casting as a date value and then checking to see if the casted value is greater than the other is not working as expected.

I've attached a pic of the a `s.EFFECTIVE_DATE` NOT being GREATER THAN the `t.StatusEffectiveDate` and why it would be showing up in my result set.  That is my question.

Here is my code where the bolded AND statement below the WHERE clause if the problem:

```
DECLARE @peims2016SnapshotDate date = '2016-10-28'
        SELECT t.StudentID, t.Status, s.status, t.StatusEffectiveDate, s.effective_date, t.enddate, @peims2016SnapshotDate as peimssnapshotdate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, -1, t.Enddate),101) as NewEndDate
        FROM Mcsfwisdtest.FRA.dbo.vw_HHSurvey s
        INNER JOIN Fwisddw.dbo.Focus_Export_Econ_DisadvantagedHHS_TEST t
        ON s.CustomerID = t.StudentID
        AND s.SiteID = LocationID
        WHERE CAST(t.Enddate as date) > @peims2016SnapshotDate 
        **AND CAST(s.effective_date as date) > CAST(t.StatusEffectiveDate as date)**
        AND t.[Status] = 'PAID' AND s.[Status] != 'PAID' 
        OR (t.[Status] = 'REDUCED' AND s.[Status] = 'FREE')
        ORDER BY t.StudentID asc
```

Comment: The biggest issue here is storing dates as varchar. And then your varchar values are not stored in ANSI standard. You will need to add the proper style to ensure how the convert happens.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert to `date` using the correct style (which in your case is style `101`):

```
DECLARE @peims2016SnapshotDate date = '2016-10-28'

SELECT  t.StudentID, 
        t.Status, 
        s.status, 
        t.StatusEffectiveDate, 
        s.effective_date, 
        t.enddate, 
        @peims2016SnapshotDate as peimssnapshotdate, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,-1,t.Enddate),101) as NewEndDate
FROM Mcsfwisdtest.FRA.dbo.vw_HHSurvey s
INNER JOIN Fwisddw.dbo.Focus_Export_Econ_DisadvantagedHHS_TEST t
    ON s.CustomerID = t.StudentID
    AND s.SiteID = LocationID
WHERE CAST(t.Enddate as date) > @peims2016SnapshotDate 
AND CONVERT(date,s.effective_date,101) > CONVERT(date,t.StatusEffectiveDate,101)
AND ((t.[Status] = 'PAID' AND s.[Status] != 'PAID') 
OR (t.[Status] = 'REDUCED' AND s.[Status] = 'FREE'))
ORDER BY t.StudentID asc;
```

Comment: My apologies.  That worked.  I appreciate your help!  Thanks.

Comment: @Melinda I see. You had another error with the logic in your `OR` condition. I updated my answer now

Comment: Thank you Lamak.  I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @Melinda no problem